# svelte - import dependency package with error

Tags: svelte-3

I am new with `Svelte` and trying to `import` some package.

After the `npm install`, I import it directly into my `svelte` file:

```
import jspdf from "jspdf"
```

that got me the error:

> Error: UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for
> code-splitting builds.

then I tried to use CDN and import via `HTML`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.1.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

and the `svelte` give me `undefined` error from:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

I googled and some some comments and it seems like the first solution should already be working. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add **inlineDynamicImports: true** in rollul.config.js at the export, like this:

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        inlineDynamicImports: true
    },
```