# Why does Rollup complain about code-splitting when I am not code-splitting?

Tags: typescript, rollup, iife, code-splitting

With only one `output` entry in my `rollup.config.js` like so:

```
export default {
  input: './src/Index.tsx',
  output: {
    dir: './myBundle/bundle',
    format: 'iife',
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    nodeResolve(),
    commonjs(),
    babel(),
    json(),
    terser(),
  ],
};
```

Why does Rollup accuse me of code-splitting?
`[!] Error: UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for code-splitting builds.`

Comment: Apparently from glancing at some github threads that came up when I googled your error message, you can't use dynamic imports with rollup if you're doing IIFE or UMD. If you're not using dynamic imports in your Typescript code, then IDK.

Comment: I am using dynamic imports in my Typescript code. Does this mean my only option is to use ES module format in my output?

Comment: No you can use commonjs (and probably AMD although I didn't check). You just can't use IIFE or UMD. But the dynamic import is why it's complaining about code splitting. Given how many github issues pop up on different repositories when you google that message, I'd say they may want a clearer one.

Comment: My issue with CommonJS is that it outputs `require` into my bundle, which is not defined in the browser.

Answer (score 21):

Encountered this problem using Routify. Adding `inlineDynamicImports: true` in rollup.config.js solved the problem for me

```
export default {
input: "src/main.ts",
output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "public/build/bundle.js",
    inlineDynamicImports: true, //Add this
},
```

[svelte - import dependency package with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679496/svelte-import-dependency-package-with-error)

Comment: inlineDynamicImports will early to bring side effect

Answer (score 2):

You should set `format` equal to `esm` or `es`

Comment: setting inlineDynamicImports to true resolved the issue for me even when format is set to 'system' as creates umd and es outputs. 
sorry I got only one vote on this